# Strange Python behaviour when using timer in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, QBasicTimer


class Example(QObject):

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        print "timer event, timer Id:", event.timerId()



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    timer = QBasicTimer()
    timer.start(500, ex) 
    print timer

    timer = QBasicTimer()
    timer.start(300, ex) 
    print timer

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

#Run it
main()
```

With this code I would expect to see 2 different kinds of output which differ in timer id. But the output is:

```
<PyQt4.QtCore.QBasicTimer object at 0xb69b90>
<PyQt4.QtCore.QBasicTimer object at 0xb69c08>
timer event, timer Id: 33554433
timer event, timer Id: 33554433
timer event, timer Id: 33554433
timer event, timer Id: 33554433
timer event, timer Id: 33554433
timer event, timer Id: 33554433
```

What is also strange is that if I change the name of variable for second timer like this:

```
    timer = QBasicTimer()
    timer.start(500, ex) 
    print timer

    timer2 = QBasicTimer()
    timer2.start(300, ex) 
    print timer2
```

Then I get the expected result:

```
<PyQt4.QtCore.QBasicTimer object at 0x17b3b90>
<PyQt4.QtCore.QBasicTimer object at 0x17b3c08>
timer event, timer Id: 16777218
timer event, timer Id: 1
timer event, timer Id: 16777218
timer event, timer Id: 16777218
timer event, timer Id: 1
timer event, timer Id: 16777218
timer event, timer Id: 1
timer event, timer Id: 16777218
timer event, timer Id: 16777218
timer event, timer Id: 1
```

I am trying to understand Python and this really confuses me. What is causing this behavior? How does the name of a variable can change the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would think the behaviour is strange. The order of events is simply this:

```
ex = Example()
# timer(1) object is created
timer = QBasicTimer()
# ex object registers timer(1)
timer.start(500, ex) 
print timer

# timer(2) object is created
# timer(1) object is destroyed
# timer(1) destructor unregisters timer(1)
timer = QBasicTimer()
# ex object registers timer(2)
timer.start(300, ex) 
print timer

# event loop starts, 300ms later, timer(2) event is processed...
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So this is just ordinary python garbage-collection at work. The creation of a second object with the same name removes the only reference to the first object, which immediately gets garbage-collected. And of course, the second object doesn't get garbage-collected itself, because the event-loop prevents the function from returning

If you didn't read the documentation for [QBasicTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbasictimer.html), I suppose you might have thought that this line:

```
timer.start(500, ex)
```

would make `ex` the parent of `timer` and hence keep it alive. But for that to work, `QBasicTimer` would have to be a subclass of `QObject` - which it isn't.

The `QBasicTimer.start()` method is actually equivalent to this:

```
def start(self, msec, obj):
    self.stop()
    if obj is not None:
        self.id = obj.startImer(msec)
```

Comment: I read the documentation for `QBasicTimer` but there is nothing mentioned about the implementation. I am kinda scared by thinking where was I supposed to get this idea and what other mysterious problems await me. Anyway it is really strange, that timer gets destroyed in the middle of its execution.

Comment: @LeNoob. You don't need to understand the implementation: I was just trying to explain what's going on. But I'm still surprised that you think any of this is "mysterious". Are you new to Python, or just PyQt? The timer did not get destroyed in the "middle of its execution", because nothing can happen (in terms of events) until the event-loop starts. And in any case, it is part of the design of Qt timers that they automatically stop themselves when they are deleted. Does that not seem reasonable to you?

Comment: I am relatively new to Python and completely new  to PyQt:) I am primarily Java developer and I have evidently problems grasping internals of Python, in this case how garbage collecting works (not to mention threading here omg). I tried to read docs & stuff but I simply could not make sense of it.